# Optimize speed of writing to excel sheet from Qt app

Tags: c++, excel, qt

I want to write a considerably large amount of data to an excel sheet through my Qt app. I currently use following code.

```
QAxObject* pExcel = new QAxObject("Excel.Application", 0);
QAxObject* pWorkbooks = pExcel->querySubObject("Workbooks");
QAxObject* pWorkbook = pWorkbooks->querySubObject("Open(const QString&)", s_FilePath);
QAxObject* pWorksheet = pWorkbook->querySubObject("Worksheets(int)", 1);

for (int i = 0; i < iColumnCount; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < iRowCount; ++j)
    {
        QAxObject* pCell = pWorksheet->querySubObject("Cells(Int, Int)", i + 1, j + 1);
        pCell->setProperty("Value", "somevalue");
    }
}
```

But, pCell->setProperty() is pretty slow and it takes a long time to set all values this way.

Does anybody know a better way to set values faster?

Comment: Use threads if you have multiple cores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to bulk update cells by updating a range of cells at once from [this](http://www.qtforum.org/article/34059/qt-and-excel-writing-a-range-of-rows-columns-to-a-worksheet.html) post which solved the problem.

Here is the code copied from the post.

```
QAxObject* excel = new QAxObject( "Excel.Application", 0 );
excel->dynamicCall("SetVisible(bool)",true);
QAxObject *workbooks = excel->querySubObject( "Workbooks" );
QAxObject *workbook = workbooks->querySubObject("Add()");

QAxObject *sheets = workbook->querySubObject( "Worksheets" );

QAxObject *sheet1 = sheets->querySubObject( "Item( int )", 1 );
sheet1->dynamicCall("SetName(const QString&)", QVariant(sheet1Name));

int n;
QList< QVariant> table;
for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    QList row;
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
    n = i*5+j;
    row.append(QVariant(n));
    }
    table.append(QVariant(row));
}

//get a 5x5 range of cells : from A1 to E5 
QAxObject *range = sheet1->querySubObject( "Range(const QString&, const QString&)", QString("A1"), QString("E5"));
QVariant vTable(table);
range->dynamicCall("SetValue(const QVariant&)", vTable);
```